# Secure access to windows machine deployed in ovh cloud

Tags: windows, cloud, ovh

I have a windows machine deployed on OVH cloud, and every one could access to it, if the use has the login and the password, is there a way please prevent any one else except me to connect eventhough the user has the right credentiels for example allow anly the IP adress of my ow laptop ..could you help please ?

NothingNothingNothingNothing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the OVH Firewall: https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-ca-dedicated-servers-firewall-network?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0043446

You'll be able to limit RDP (Windows remote desktop) to only your IP.

You can also add MFA to your Windows Server like DUO, to add a layer of security.

The best thing to do is to keep your server updated, with a strong password and multi factor authentication.